# How to escape subfolder in slim3 framework being routed by slim3

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, slim-3

I have a project built with slim 3 and is working as expected (http://localhost/slimapp/). Now what I want to do is in one of the subfolder run an Angular2 application. But as I try to access the subfolder (http://localhost/slimapp/angularapp/) via browser it is redirected to index.php of slim3, which is quite obvious. What I want to achieve is when I visit http://localhost/slimapp/angularapp/ this URL should not be redirected through slim3 .htaccess and it should run an angular application.

So far I tried in .htaccess is add

```
RewriteRule ^angularapp($|/) - [L,NC]
```

This results in 404 not found a page for http://localhost/slimapp/angularapp/.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of rewriting it on the .htaccess level, just create a web-route from slim for that particular path, so instead of you accessing it from the browser, you would access Slim App, and it will access the angular app for you.